# Response time of google search engine

Tags: google-search, yandex, yahoo-search, bing-search

Does anybody know, 
I need to compare the response time of my search engine with google, for my own search engine i could calculate the response time with using JavaScript codes but for google I don't know how to do it.
How can I calculate the response time of google search engine for searching a query? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google reports the query time at the start of all results:

example (search "test")

> About 2,460,000,000 results (0.46 seconds)

Comment: Then How can I find this response time in other search engines, I need the same response time for Bing,Yahoo, AOL,Ask.com,Dogpile and Yandex

Answer (score 0):

Just go to [Alerta](http://alerta.com) to check server's response time, or open your command line tool on your device and ping it.

Comment: more of a comment